# Prime degree ⇒ linearly disjoint?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> If *F* is a field of characteristic 0 with subfields *K*, *L* such that *F* is the compositum of *K* and *L* and [ *L* : *L* ∩ *K* ] is prime, must be *K* and *L* be linearly disjoint over *L* ∩ *K*?
>
> In other words, must [ *KL* : *K* ] = [ *L* : *L* ∩ *K* ] if [ *L* : *L* ∩ *K* ] is prime?

Here *K*, *L* are fields of characteristic 0 (definitely not *p*), but I don't assume [ *K* : *K* ∩ *L* ] is finite (or normal or anything).  I think it doesn't have to be true if that index [ *L* : *L* ∩ *K* ] is not prime and the field extension *K* ∩ *L* ≤ *K* is not normal.  I am hoping it is true when the index [ *L* : *L* ∩ *K* ] is prime.

The motivation is to show either every non-identity *p*-subgroup of PGL(2, *K*) is reducible or every non-identity *p*-subgroup of PGL(2, *K*) is irreducible.

Comment: A pair of fields $L,K$ are said to be linearly disjoint over $E$ if $L\otimes_{E}K$ is a field. Is this what you are interested in? If so, what is E?

Comment: E = L ∩ K, sorry.

Comment: I think though, that is the only possible value for E.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no. Let $L = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5})$ and $K = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3\sqrt[3]{5}).$ Then $[LK:L] = 2 \neq 3 = [L: K\cap L]$ and $L\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} K$ is not a field.

**Edit in responce to the comment:** For any fields $L$ and $K,$ if $L/L\cap K$ is finite, Galois, then so too is $KL/K$ and $[LK : K]$ divides $[L:L\cap K].$

Consequently, if $[L:L\cap K]$ is prime then $L\neq K$ and $[LK : K] = [L:L\cap K].$

Linear disjointness follows, assume momentarily that $K/L\cap K$ is finite and set $E = L\cap K.$ Then $$\mathrm{dim}_{E}(L\otimes_{\mathbb{E}} K) = [L:E][K:E] = [LK : K][K:E] = dim_{E}(LK).$$ Hence, the natural ring epimorphism from $L\otimes_{\mathbb{E}} K$ to $LK$ is an isomorphism of $E$-vector spaces and hence a ring isomorphism. It follows $L\otimes_{\mathbb{E}} K$ is a field.

For the case where $K/E$ is infinite,

Let $\mathcal{K} :=\{K'\}$ be the collection of fields which are finite extensions of $E$ and contained in $K.$ Then

$L\otimes_{\mathbb{E}} K \cong L\otimes_{\mathbb{E}} (\displaystyle\lim_{\rightarrow}K') \cong \displaystyle\lim_{\rightarrow}(L\otimes_{\mathbb{E}} K') \cong \displaystyle\lim_{\rightarrow} LK' \cong LK.$

where colimits are taken over $\mathcal{K}.$ It follows $L\otimes_{\mathbb{E}} K$ is a field and $K$ and $L$ are linearly disjoint.

Comment: Crud.  This doesn't answer my hidden question though.  I do have that L∩K ≤ L is Galois.  Probably should have mentioned that.  If it is easy to adjust to this, could you please?  Otherwise, I'll ask as another question.

Comment: If both L and K are Galois over the intersection, then it is not difficult to show that they are linearly disjoint (irrespective of whether the extension degree is a prime or not). I need to think about it more, if only one is Galois.

Comment: @Jyrki: thanks!  If K is finite dimensional over K∩L, then they are linearly disjoint, I believe.  I just have no references for the infinite dimensional case.

Comment: @Jack: Sorry, I meant to write: if both $K$ and $L$ are finite and Galois over $K\cap L$, then they are linearly disjoint. Don't know if the proof works for infinite extensions :-(

Comment: @jspecter: Thanks!  Do you have a reference for the first sentence of your edit?  (KL/L is Galois).  I only know it for K/E finite.

Comment: @JS. Prove it for finite extensions and then take the compositum.

Comment: @jspecter: I don't know how to do that.  Both the base field and the extension field are changing.

Comment: Ah, never mind it is easy to prove it for all K.